# Is there a way to use distribute points on faces/volume on animated geometry?

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry

I like to animate geometry using noise texture/scenetime and then set position in the offset but when I do this the points will randomly change every frame unlike with mesh to points which works with instance on points just fine but sometimes it is more desirable to randomly scatter. Is there a way to create a random scatter then somehow freeze the seed in place and then animate the source mesh with the offset?  I know there is a way to do this with the scatter node in Houdini but not sure if Blender is capable of that yet.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to deform and animate geometry in Blender so the specifics will differ depending on the way you choose to deform the geometry, but the idea remains the same - you need to distribute points first, then animate so that the points get deformed, then instance something on those points. If you keep your animation in Geometry nodes, that's very easy, just deform the distributed points with geometry before instancing like this for example:

[image]

If you animate the geometry some other way, you need to make sure that whatever deforms it does so after points are distributed. So you might need a few geometry nodes modifiers and to convert distributed points to vertices and then store some attribute in them so you can separate them in the next Geometry Nodes modifier after deformation.

[image]

So in this situation if I animated the Simple Deform modifier inbetween the 2 Geometry Nodes modifiers, the distributed points would deform with the rest of geometry, but instances would be placed on the deformed points.

Comment: Thatsh good informashion. I am animating by normal offset and it wasn't working with points but adding the points to vertices fixed it. Thank you Ron.